# How to retrieve an environmental variable from a path that is present in file,

Tags: c++

For example we have a path like this:

```
\$ALLO/abc/bcd/cde.txt
```

Here `ALLO` is an environmental variable which is already defined in my Unix environment. `ALLO=/home/kiran/`. I want to read that path from the file and replace that environmental variable with absolute path.

Here the critical part for me is priorly I don't know the name of the environmental variable while reading the path. so I cannot use the `getenv()` function here.

Comment: If you know the name of the environment variable you can use getenv, if you don't know the name of the environment variable the problem is impossible. I don't understand why you think you can't use getenv (which is the only way to get an environment variable).

Comment: You could take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/172644/103739

Comment: what file? Is is a `bash` file, is is a `ini` file? What exactly is the input and what result do you expect? What OS?

Comment: It is a text file. In that I have to read .axe format path, in that path an environmental variable is present. I have to replace that enviromentaa variable with absolute path. For example the path is like \$ALLO/abc/bsd/abc.axe. In that i have to replace the ALLo with its path. Here ALLO is an example. The env variable name may changes

Comment: Hi @JVApen 
Will you pease help me in writing that without regex

Comment: @KiranGnanesh std::regex is standard c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your text file contains `\$SOMENAME/` as part of the line, and you do NOT know what `SOMENAME` will be beforehand, you can still extract what is between `\$...../` and send that to `getenv` to obtain the contents of the environment variable `SOMENAME` -- even though you don't know that name to start with.

You can do this by reading each line and using `size_t begin = line.find("$");` and then locating the `end` with `end = line.find("/", begin);` You can then use `.substr()` to extract the environment variable name from `line` before calling `getenv()`. For example you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string line, envpath;

    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);

    while (getline (f, line)) {                     /* read each line */
        size_t begin = line.find("$");              /* search for '$' */
        if (begin != std::string::npos) {           /* contains '$'? */
            size_t end = line.find("/", begin);     /* find following '/' */
            /* extract environment variable from line */
            std::string envvar = line.substr (begin + 1, end - 2);
            /* get from environment (NULL returned if it does not exist) */
            if (const char *envtmp = std::getenv(envvar.c_str()))
                envpath = envtmp;
            else {
                std::cerr << "error: $" << envvar << " not in environment.\n";
                continue;
            }
            /* replace variable name with contents in line */
            line.replace (begin - 1, end - begin + 1, envpath);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (envpath.length())
        std::cout << "absolute path: " << line << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "error: environment variable not found.\n";
}
```

(**note:** if you have multiple variable names in the file, e.g. `\$...../` you can adjust the logic to fit your needs.)

**Example Input File**

Using your input line contained in a file with a few other lines around it:

```
$ cat dat/envinpath.txt
some lines of text
\$ALLO/abc/bcd/cde.txt
more lines of text
```

**Example Use/Output**

Exporting `ALLO` as my home directory path and then running the program successfully extracts `ALLO` from the line and then uses `getenv()` to get the environment variable contents and then `.replace()` to substitute the contents for the variable name before outputting the results, e.g.

```
$ export ALLO=$HOME

$ ./bin/genvfrompath dat/envinpath.txt
absolute path: /home/david/abc/bcd/cde.txt
```

Look things over and let me know if this is what your were intending. If not, let me know and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: You are welcome. Note, there are always more validations you can add. For example, if `end == std::string::npos` (meaning there is nothing following `\$ALLO` in the line), you would need to adjust the number of characters replaced by `-1` since there is no `'/'` to replace. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use the getenv() function here.

Why do you think that you cannot use getenv here?

Since you know the name of the env variable, then you should use getenv function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/

`char *envPath = getenv("ALLO");`

This should be it.

Comment: Quote from OP: ` is priorly I dont know the name`

Comment: priorly I dont know the name of the environmental variable. I have to read it from the path in a file which is followed by /$

Comment: @KiranGnanesh So what is stopping you using getenv **after** you've worked out what the variable name is? You seem to be seeing problems which don't exist.

Comment: So, you know how to get env variable value. But you do not know how to get env var name. So solution is pretty simple. 1) find the env var name. How? You said it, it is written in file. Open file for reading, and find it

Comment: ok then help me with this
 In the path given below 
            {\$XXXX/abc/bcd/cde.txt}
 I'm ok upto reading this path
please help me in finding the env variable from the above path so that i can use getenv function

Comment: ok just to clarify, you get `{\$XXXX/abc/bcd/cde.txt}` this in you program? Or do you need to locate this in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Here what exactly I need is the equalent code of the following code because i dont have the regex header in my environment

```
        inline std::string ExpandEnv(std::string &&text)
        {
            static const std::regex ENV{"\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}"};
            std::smatch match;
            while (std::regex_search(text, match, ENV)) text.replace(match.begin()->first, match[0].second, GetEnv(match[1].str().c_str()));
             return text;
         }

         inline std::string ExpandEnv(std::string const &text)
         {
          return ExpandEnv(std::string(text));
         }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: So you are looking for a `$` followed by `{` followed by the name (which doesn't contain `}`) followed by `}`. It's a simple loop.

Comment: But in the question, there's no `{` following the `$`.

Comment: Will you please eloborate that condition. I want to do the above code without that regex

Comment: The path may be  in different ways like {\$ALLO/abc/bcd/cde.txt} \$ALLO/abc/bcd/cde.txt

Comment: @KiranGnanesh One problem here is that your regex is not the same as your examples. In your examples the `{}` are optional, in your examples the `$` is after the `{` not before. In your examples there's a backslash before the `$`. None of these things are true in the regex. If you want some code written for you then you need to be clear about exactly what you want. On the other hand if you write the code (or least attempt to) then you'll get what you want,

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to C++ standard then use of regular expression is some solution (IMO very fragile).

I would do that using system library, what will give me warranty that it will work in same way as system. System library I would hide behind a functin/class which should be system specyfic.

On Linux/Unix there is [wordexpr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html).

On Windows there is [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa).

```cpp
// linux example
#include <string>
#include <wordexp.h>

std::string expand_string(const std::string& s)
{
    wordexp_t p;
    char** w;
    wordexp(s.c_str(), &p, 0);

    std::string r;

    if (p.we_wordc > 0) {
        r.reserve(std::max(s.size(), 255ull));
        r.append(p.we_wordv[0]);
    }
    for (int i=1; i < p.we_wordc; ++i) {
        r.append(" ");
        r.append(p.we_wordv[i]);
    }

    wordfree(&p);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Here I need to modify the QString